# Ссылка на дочерние элементы в layout с merge

Tags: android, include

Здравствуйте,

сделал свой аналог **numericUpDown**, т.е. поле с двумя кнопками, которые увеличивают или уменьшают значение. Одна и та же разметка довольно часто используется, поэтому хотел бы на нее ссылаться с помощью **include** и **merge**.

Есть следующий файл разметки **reference_linear_layout_up_down_numeric_buttons**:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
&gt;

 <Button
     android:layout_width="60dp"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:text="٨"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/buttonArrowUp"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
 >
 </Button>
 <Button
     android:layout_width="60dp"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:text="٧"
     android:gravity="center"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:id="@+id/buttonArrowDown"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
 >
 </Button>

</merge>
```

В основном меню идет отсылка на разметку **reference_linear_layout_up_down_numeric_buttons**:

```
  <include layout = "@layout/reference_linear_layout_up_down_numeric_buttons"

  android:id="@+id/layoutUpDownNumberOfStars"
  />
```

Как теперь можно в java программе сослаться на кнопки ?

Например если я напишу вот так:

```
  View  mView_LayoutView = findViewById(R.id.layoutUpDownNumerOfStars);

  Button mButtonUp = mView_LayoutView.findViewById(R.id.buttonArrowUp);
```

То компилятор выдает ошибку **NullPointerException**.

Если написать вот так:

```
  Button mButtonUp = findViewById(R.id.buttonArrowUp);
```

То будет неоднозначная ситуация например если несколько ссылок в основной разметке на разметку **reference_linear_layout_up_down_numeric_buttons** с кнопками.

Как в этом случае нужно правильно сослаться на кнопки в java программе?

Заранее большое спасибо всем за ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить ссылку на `merge` нельзя. Используется он (как я понял из доков) для возможности заменить 2 include 1 merge.

Засим, отличить кнопки из merge друг от друга можно лишь по их родителю. Т.е. нельзя поместить два идетичных `merge` в один контейнер. Ведь в этом случае у вас будет один и тот же ID у нескольких элементов.

Но вы можете поместить по одному `merge` в разные контейнеры в одной общей разметке и находить их через эти контейнеры.

```
containerView.findViewById(...).;
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. 1)  а id ссылки ** android:id="@+id/layoutUpDownNumberOfStars"** не может как то помочь различить две ссылки на **reference_linear_layout_up_down_numeric_buttons** ?                       2) Не могли бы вы поподробнее расписать пример с двумя контейнерами в одной общей разметке.

Comment: @foxis, назначение ID для `merge` не имеет смыла, т.к. он не представляет собой элемент разметки. то, что его можно вообще проставить - недоработка IDE. 2) Вам надо или заменить тэг `merge` на что-то типа `FrameLayout` или делать `include` с `merge` внутри в к-л контейнер (тот же `FrameLayout`). Да, так будут "лишние" элементы в разметке, но иначе невозможно на один уровень поместить элементы с уникальным идентификатором.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 2) Если ставить дополнительно **FrameLayout**, то тогда в принципе теряется смысл вообще использовать **merge**. Ведь **merge** нужен для того чтобы убрать лишний контейнер, например, **LinearLayout** и тем самым улучшить производительность уменьшив нагрузку на обработку дополнительного контейнера. Получается ,что сохранить преимущества merge в производительности и одновременно ссылаться на его дочерние элементы в нескольких местах программы по сути невозможно.

Comment: @foxis, да, `merge` не панацея для всего. Он полезен лишь в ряде случаев типа расположения набора кнопок типа "ОК", "Отмена", "Закрыть". Лично мне не очень понятно зачем его вообще сделали - никогда мне он не пригождался.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Примерная картина применяемости инструмента **merge** ясна.